# WkWebview contentOffset not working when settign animated false

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I need to set contentOffset of WkWebView as soon as contents finished to load.  I set `webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)` inside webview didFinish navigation.

If I set animated to `true`, it works but when I set it to `false`, webView does not scroll.

How can I scroll webview without animating?

Comment: This documentation might explain the reason why this is happening: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollingViewContent/ScrollingViewContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH6-SW3 When `animated: true` it sends a series of events, and when it's `animated: false` is sends a single event.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) animated:NO];
}
```

or you can use JavaScript

```
NSString *script = @"scrollTo(0, 0)";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```